# Improving the speed of a Python solution to the Lead Game exercise

Tags: python, optimization, profiling

Here is my solution to [the Lead Game problem on Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TLG). It runs fine, but took 2.63 sec and 3.8M memory, while I saw many C programs that had completed in 0.08 seconds and 1.6M memory. How can I make it faster?

```
import sys
cnt = int(sys.stdin.readline())
match = [[int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().split()] for i in range(cnt)]
diff=[]
for i in range(cnt):
      if i!=0:
             match[i]=[sum(vals) for vals in zip(match[i-1],match[i])]
      diff.append([1 if max(match[i])==match[i][0] else 2,abs(match[i][0]-match[i][1])])
maxval = max(diff,key=lambda x:x[1])
sys.stdout.write(str(maxval[0]) + ' ' + str(maxval[1]))
```

Comment: have you tried to run your code with profiler? What part is the most time-consuming?

Comment: @dbf: I didn't. How do I do that. It'd be great if you could point me somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Are you opposed to using 3rd party packages (e.g. `numpy`)?  I'd imaging you could get some speed performance there.

Comment: 2.63sec for the few lines? Are you measuring the time to type the input too? The memory consumption is possible, since Python has more overhead than C, but the time doesn't seem realistic.

Comment: @mankand007 check these links: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script

Comment: Also, you could get rid of the test `if i!=0` by having the loop go: `for i in range(1,cnt)`.

Comment: @mgilson: I'm just learning python and trying to optimize my coding style here. So, I would prefer an answer in the line of 'Dos and Don'ts', 'Best Practices', and sorts... 
And I can't skip the 0th element as I need to process that too. Only, I don't want to try and refer to its previous element.

Comment: you should add the input data for your code so we can test it

Comment: Too much array manipulation, I feel. You could do this without `zip` and `max` - it's just two numbers; two plusses and a comparison should suffice.

Comment: But skipping the 0th element still allows you to access it with `i-1` as you already have. And it'll let you eliminate the `if` statement that will be executed every time through the loop but that is almost always `True`.

Comment: @eumiro: The input was given by the test system via sysin, and yes the code took that long from start to end.

Comment: @F.C: The input data is present in the link provided. I didn't give it here because it would seem irrelevent without the problem statement. Here it is 
`Input: `
`5`
`140 82`
`89 134`
`90 110`
`112 106`
`88 90`
`Output:`
`1 58`

Comment: @mgilson: I'm not appending [1]. I'm appending a list of two elements:
[largest among the two elements(1 or 2 being its position), difference between them]
 And the code runs fine and was accepted by the system for correct results

Comment: @mankand007 -- You're right.  (my brain inserted an extra parnethesis on the rhs of the ternary operator)

Comment: Also, your big problem: comparing C with Python :P It's rather obvious C will be faster and run in less memory. I will also bet that C will do it one row at a time, without loading the whole set into memory, without comprehensions, without `max`, only with comparisons, additions and one single "while not end of file" loop. While you could use some of the same techniques, you probably don't want to write Python in quite the same way as C. :P

Comment: @Amadan: Well, Python might be slower than C, but there is also a huge factor called 'Programmer Efficiency'. I just want to improve that so that I can be worthier of my weapons in the battles.. :P

Comment: @mankand007: I agree with that wholeheartedly - I don't even remember when I last did something serious in a compiled language. However, you didn't compare a day on C code versus an hour on Python, you compared Python running in 2.63 sec while C ran in 0.08. All I'm saying is that that particular comparison is rather silly. Compare your Python with other people's Python; if you have to, compare to Ruby, Perl or Lua; but against C or compiled OCaml or C++, Python can't help but lose in execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the memory footprint (Python data structures take a little more space, and it's normal) and also it's hard to expect a Python script to beat a C program in terms of speed.

**Edit**: no need to keep leads history

My O(n) algorithm ran in 1.18 seconds:

```
import sys

rounds = int(sys.stdin.readline())

score = [0,0]
leads = [0,0]
while rounds > 0:
    results = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    score[0] += results[0]
    score[1] += results[1]
    lead = score[0] - score[1]
    if (lead < 0 and leads[1] < -lead): leads[1] = -lead
    if (lead > 0 and leads[0] < lead): leads[0] = lead
    rounds -= 1

if (leads[0] > leads[1]): print 1, leads[0]
else: print 2, leads[1]
```

**Edit**

To see where your algorithm  spends most time you can use:

```
cat inputfile | python -m cProfile yourScript.py
```

Comment: why do you keep the whole history instead of just keeping the max lead?

Comment: I don't think your solution is giving the correct answer, given the input I tested it on.

Comment: @MattAnderson well, I submitted it in the competition, and it was [accepted](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/1090082)

Comment: Thanks for the code, and for pointing me in a different direction of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quick inspiration looks that you have O(n^2) algorithm, where you could use O(n) algorithm.

Instead of

```
 for:
    for: #this for  comes from line whit list comprehension
```

Just assemble one or multiple for loops (but not nested for loops).

It is not problem, that python si too slow, just your algorithm is not efficient enough

EDIT

I was wrong, maybe append is just too slow. Try using comprehension

so diff is just (out of for loop)

```
diff = [[1 if max(m)==m[0] else 2,abs(m[0]-m[1])] for m in match]
```

and use try to use tuples:

code is then.

```
import sys
cnt = int(sys.stdin.readline())
match = [tuple(int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().split()) for i in range(cnt)]
diff=[]
for i in range(cnt):
   if i!=0:
         match[i]=tuple(sum(vals) for vals in zip(match[i-1],match[i]))
diff = [tuple((1 if max(m)==m[0] else 2,abs(m[0]-m[1]))) for m in match]
maxval = max(diff,key=lambda x:x[1])
sys.stdout.write(str(maxval[0]) + ' ' + str(maxval[1]))
```

Comment: If I'm reading the code right, the comprehension should always be over a 2 element array, so it's actually `O(2n)` (which is equivalent to `O(n)`). You can't measure complexity just by counting `for` statements, without seeing what they are doing.

Comment: At lest line:
match[i]=[sum(vals) for vals in zip(match[i-1],match[i])] run time is depended on N. And it runs N times. So in total O(N*N) time.

Comment: Yes, that's the line I'm talking about. I don't see how it depends on N. `match[i-1]` has 2 elements (`[playerAScore, playerBScore]`); `match[i]` has 2 elements. `zip` is 2 elements long, so it is `O(2)` for each row, not `O(n)`. I think `zip` then `max` is overkill, but it doesn't make it `O(n^2)`.

Comment: The above code ran for 4.08 secs with 3.9M memory. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion, and +1 for advising to first determine the type of algorithm needed.